# RabbitMQ, is it possible to consume 1 message from a channel while keep it FIFO?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, messagebroker

I am using RabbitMQ with C# as a message broker framework.
In my scenario I have many consumers which can consume from different queues.
several queues form a logical group from the perspective of a consumer.

for example:
Queue1,Queue2,Queue3.

Consumer1 will want to take first message from [Queue1,Queue3] and only if not available try to take from Queue2

Consumer2 will want to take first message from [Queue2,Queue3] and only if not available try to take from Queue1

Below is a possible setup, each Consumer care about subset of queues.
Consumer2 interested in all the queues, in priorities 1,2, hence the consumer maintain the priorities logic.
Note that this is a different scenario from the work queues that are presented here [RabbitMQ tutorials](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html)
[image]

Here is a class which supposed to return a message:

```
public class MessagesProvider
{

    private IConnection _connection;
    private IModel _channel;
    private readonly IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _tagsQueueItems;
    private EventingBasicConsumer _consumer;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private TaskCompletionSource<BasicGetResult> _tcs;

    public MessagesProvider()
    {
        _connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = "localhost"
        };

    }

    public Task<BasicGetResult> GetMessage(int timeout, IEnumerable<string> queues)
    {
        _tagsQueueItems = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _connection = _connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        _channel = _connection.CreateModel();
        _channel.SingleMessagePerChannel();
        _consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
        _consumer.Received += OnReceive;

        foreach (var queue in queues)
        {
            var tag = _channel.BasicConsume(queue, false, _consumer);
            _tagsQueueItems.AddOrUpdate(queue, tag, (k, o) => queue);
        }

        return _tcs.Task;
    }

    private void SetResult(BasicGetResult result)
    {
        _tcs.SetResult(result);
        if (_channel.IsOpen)
            _channel.Close();
        if (_connection.IsOpen)
            _connection.Close();
    }

    private void OnReceive(object sender, BasicDeliverEventArgs e)
    {
        _consumer.Received -= OnReceive;
        _channel.BasicAck(e.DeliveryTag, false);
        var result = new BasicGetResult(e.DeliveryTag, e.Redelivered, e.Exchange, e.RoutingKey, 1,
            e.BasicProperties, e.Body);

        SetResult(result);

    }
}
```

Channel definition:

```
 public static class  ChannelExtension
{
    public static void SingleMessagePerChannel(this IModel channel)
    {
        channel.BasicQos(0,1,true);
    }

    public static void SingleMessagePerConsumer(this IModel channel)
    {
        channel.BasicQos(0,1,false);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am registering for a queue one by one (in method "GetMessage"), and I was not able to find an "atomic" operation which brings the next FIFO message from a group of queues.

I am looking for a way to do this:
_consumer.getNextMessage();

**Another approach** would be to consume all the first most messages from the first group of priority, filter them on the consumer side to find the oldest message and send no ack for the other messages (in the same priority group).
This approach is problematic as well since it means that at a point of fetching the messages, other consumer will not be able to handle them (until no ack).

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you have the setup wrong. Could you please elaborate what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: +1 to @cantSleepNow - this whole scenario seems like a bad design, and what you want to do isn't really possible without major problems. what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @cantSleepNow,@Derick Bailey, I agree with you the design is bad and I don't like it, setting the priority at the consumer level is wrong IMO however it is required by the clients of a currently working system.What I need to achieve is to allow third party consumers to define what messages are important for them. each consumer has it's own priorities. It's a more complex scenario than just load balance a work between consumers of the same queues which for this there is a solution out of the box using RabbitMQ. You can look at the diagram closer, it explain my needs.

Comment: Diagram is not sufficient, it looks like the one for topics tutorial https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-python.html.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using Queues and Consumers in the way they were designed.  Think of a queue as a bucket of work to be done.  Each bucket of work can have N consumers that do the work.

Each consumer should be designed to work with a single queue and not know or care about other queues or other consumers.

If you're trying to achieve a "high priority" queue then I suggest you have a single exchange with 2 different queues:

- Regular Priority Queue
- High Priority Queue

Then, by default, messages get put into the regular priority queue.  When a message comes along that needs to be high priority you can set the header on the message so that it gets pushed into the High Priority Queue.

We use this same approach today using a **direct** queue and adding a header when we want a message to go into the high priority queue.

Comment: Luckily I was able to convince the stack holders that the RabbitMQ hammer is not suitable for the problem, so they changed the problem, simplifying the requirements, they removed the complexity of different consumers consume from the different logical groups. Now all consumers will consume from the same groups which will be routed to a single queue (per group). thanks.